# C preprocessing multi pass

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-warnings, preprocessor, clang++

I'm a littlebit confused about the behaviour of preprocessing in c.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

#define myMacro anotherMacro

#define anotherMacro 6

int main()
{
    int dummy = myMacro;
    printf("dummy = %d", dummy);

    return 0;
}
```

in the above code snippet, the result will 6. however the the macro expansion in the initial pass will replace "myMacro" by "anotherMacro".
this is means that preprocessor will make a second pass to resolve "anotherMacro" to value 6.

Comment: It doesn't mean an entire second pass. It does imply a *loop* until closure when resolving the `#defines`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are chained macros resolved in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297580/how-are-chained-macros-resolved-in-c)

Answer (score -2):

The preprocessor will make a second pass. He works through the source file line per line.

So if he reaches the first define

```
#define myMacro anotherMacro
```

he will replace all occurrences of **myMacro** with the string **anotherMacro**.

The file will look like this after the line is handled:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define anotherMacro 6

int main()
{
    int dummy = anotherMacro;
    printf("dummy = %d", dummy);

    return 0;
}
```

Now the preprocessor could continue with the next #define
  and replace every **anotherMacro** with the text **6**

Comment: That's not correct. Each token is expanded whennit is encountered using the definitions in effect at that point.